# Document.cookie result is empty javascript in Codeigniter application

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session

I would like to access the SESSION ID with the document.cookie javascript property. It is working properly if I use the PHP's own session handler. It prints the following:

```
"PHPSESSID=ceahfd1r8bl6iohavkb0gsv8d0"
```

But when I try to access it within my Codeigniter app, it prints nothing, just two quotes. However according to the Google chrome there is an existing Codeigniter SESSION. Like this:

[image]

I have tried it on Firefox, Google chorme and IE 11, but nothing. I also tried to disable the security option in the CodeIgniter Session library, like session.use_strict_mode with no luck.

Edit: Is possible to the Codeigniter security library is blocking this behavior? My config file does not allow any security mod:

```
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: `$config['cookie_httponly'] = TRUE;` – means no client-side JavaScript access to this cookie, please.

Comment: Yes. But it did help me when i set it false. I had to disable in the Session library. cookie_httponly is very insecure and you can not disable it from the config file. Useful comment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. CodeIgniter Sessions are not PHP Sessions. CodeIgniter session data is encrypted.

Below citations of CodeIgniter:

> - Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.
> - Note: Even if you are not using encrypted sessions, you must set an encryption key in your config file which is used to aid in preventing session data manipulation.
> - Note: The Session class relies on the Encryption class, so you must have Mcrypt extension installed

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: How can I disable this function?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. If you can manipulate session data client side, it's very dangerous for login systems, etc. Why do you want?

Comment: I would like to build a vulnerably application to represent others, how can they prevent session hijacking, XSS, CSRF, etc.

Comment: @Greg Then don't use a framework. Frameworks strive to create a non-vulnerable environment. If you want to demonstrate security issues, you'll need to not use a system intended to prevent them.

Comment: I got it. You are warned you must NOT disable this function in the main Session file. Thanks guys.